# "Until there is no more need" in Malachi 3:10

Tags: hebrew, malachi

In Malachi 3:10 the LORD suggests (?) putting him to the test him in order to see

> אִם־לֹא אֶפְתַּ֣ח לָכֶם אֵת אֲרֻבּוֹת הַשָּׁמַיִם וַהֲרִיקֹתִי לָכֶם בְּרָכָה עַד־בְּלִי־דָי
>   if I will not open the windows of heaven for you and pour down for you a blessing until there is no more need. (ESV)

I'm having trouble with "until there is no more need." The Hebrew is literally "until there is not sufficiency" (*ʿad-bĕlı̂-dāy*) which to me means just the opposite of "until there is no more need." Of course, in context the ESV makes a lot more sense than "until there is not enough", but how does one arrive at that translation?

Comment: BDB offers: "until there is not *sufficiency*, i.e. until my abundance can be exhausted, or, as this can never be, for ever." Now there's a leap that wouldn't have occurred to me.

Comment: you really should make that an answer. It definitely answers the question and provides an enhanced understanding of the verse.

Comment: @Joshua Thanks. I'm not sure I buy it though.  NIV takes a different sort of leap: "so much blessing that there will not be room enough to store it."

Comment: "... until there no more room for it all" is probably the intended meaning, but anything indicating "beyond measure" is likely fine for capturing the intent. See [bottom of p.72 and top of 73 in Mitchell's commentary](https://archive.org/stream/criticalexegeti00mitc#page/72/mode/2up).

Answer (score 1):

The Talmud in tractate Sabbath Page 32B sees it as a play on words.

```
מאי "עד בלי די"? אמר רמי בר חמא אמר רב: עד שייבלו שפתותיכם מלומר די
```

Translation/Transliteration:

```
What does "Ad Beli Dai" mean?
Rami Bar Hama said in the name of Rav:
"Ad shibalu sefatecha melomar dai"
```

Meaning:

```
Until you lips will wear out from saying "enough"
```

Also, sometimes in Hebrew we use opposites to mean something. The most famous and well known case is calling a blind person "Sagi Nahor" which means "Plenty/Enough light".

Answer (score 0):

I studied this during 1990s & the meaning given was DAYENU . . . Not room enough for us to contain all the Blessings,  ie. Overflowing abundance. Strangely that doesn't come up when I search now - but I will always remember DAYENU - room enough

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).